# Prevent Chrome to check working internet connection

Tags: networking, google-chrome, browser

My setup:

I have a webserver which is accessible over an WIFI access point, but the server is otherwise completely offline. It just provides access to the locally hosted website.

The clients get their IP-Addresses and the DNS-Server (which is the local server) over DHCP. The server itself resolves a specific Domain to the local webserver (e.g. www.offline.com -> 192.168.0.1).

The client connects just fine, but when I enter the URL in Google Chrome, it immediately says that there is no internet connection (which is true, but the URL should be accessible anyway). After about 10 seconds the page loads like it should do. When I reload the site it appears immediately. Safari on MacOS and iOS do not show this behaviour.

So my question is: Why and how does Google Chrome checks if there is a working internet connection available? Is it possible to prevent Chrome from doing that, in order to access the website immediately and not to wait the 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

With Wireshark I noticed that Google Chrome asks the DNS resolver, which was dnsmasq in my case, for some random domains, to prevent malicious catch-all DNS resolvers. Dnsmasq did not answered correctly so it blocked it in the first place.

I had to configure dnsmasq with

```
no-resolv
```

Now Google Chrome immediately loads the page.